# Ethernet Shield 2 data to PHP server doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno, shields

I am trying to send data via GET to my PHP server from my Ethernet Shield2.
This is part of my sketch:

```
char myserver[] = "www.myserver.com/";
if (client.connect(myserver, 80)) {
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(myserver);
  client.print("GET /arduino/controller.php?");
  client.print("air_temp=");
  client.print(DS18B20_temperature);
  client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
  client.print("Host: ");
  client.println(myserver);
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();
  client.println();
} else {
  // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
  Serial.println("Connection failed to Server");
}
```

The serial monitor displays "Connect to myserver.com" but my PHP code doesn't seem to receive the `air_temp` value from DS18B20_temperature. I checked this value and it's true.

However, when I try `myserver.com/arduino/controller.php?air_temp=25` in my browser, the PHP code is running well.

What's going wrong with my code?

Comment: Try changing `char myserver[] = "www.myserver.com/";` to `char myserver[] = "www.myserver.com";` (so without tailing slash)

Comment: Hi, I changed the line with char myserver[] = "www.myserver.com"; and now the serial monitor send "Connection failed to Server".  :(

Comment: There shouldn't be a slash in the `Host` header. So create a second variable, without the slash and use that one in line behind Host...

Comment: Why create another variable ? Theproblem is that my shield does not connect to my server, Why ?

Comment: Apparently `client.connect` needs the slash at the end, while `Host: ` required no slash at the end.

Comment: When I try Shield Exemple with www.google.com (without slash) it's works!

Comment: Don't forget the client close else it will not work after 4 requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the line server.begin() and it's works !!!
Thanks.